# static variables duplicate in defined template class usage from DLL

Tags: templates, winapi, visual-c++, dll, dllexport

i have the following code in a DLL, in a header file called TemplateT:

```
#pragma once

template<class T>
class __declspec(dllexport) TemplateT {
public:
    static int number;
    TemplateT(int num) {
        number = num;
    }
    int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

};
template<class T>
int TemplateT<T>::number;
```

and on another header file called Exported.h

```
#pragma once
#include "TemplateT.h"


#define EXPORTED __declspec(dllexport)

extern EXPORTED TemplateT<int> exported;
```

and on Exported.cpp i have:

```
#include "Exporter.h"


TemplateT<int> exported(5);
```

As you can see, im initiating the static member "number" to the value of 5.
but as i access the variable from **another project** like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Exporter.h"

int main()
{
    int a = exported.getNumber();
    int b = 0;
}
```

i see the value of number as 0.
Ill be happy if you could explain to me this behavior.

**EDIT**

both are used with visual studio 2019. the dll is compiled with vs19 and the other project with vs10

I found a question about the same situation, but the answers there did not fix it for me

[two instances of static member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11666166/two-instances-of-a-static-member-how-could-that-be)

Comment: What toolchain (I assume it is Visual Studio) and C++ standard are you compiling this with?

Comment: both are used with visual studio 2019. the dll is compiled with  vs19 and the other project with vs10

Comment: I think you need `dllexport` in the project that builds the DLL, and `dllimport` everywhere else.

Comment: You mean dllexport on the exported header file? And could you explain further where to use dllimport?

Comment: @MarkRansom forgot to tag you in the last comment.

Comment: Yes, I mean the header file.  You use `dllimport` exactly the same way you use `dllexport`.

Comment: I tried that, and yet this does not work @MarkRansom

Answer (score 0):

[[SO]: DLL-Exporting static members of template base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848865/dll-exporting-static-members-of-template-base-class) provides an answer. 
Your class (and *exported* variable) has 2 instances of the static member:

1. In the *.dll* (*Exporter.cpp*) - initialized (explicitly) to 5
2. In the *.exe* (*main.cpp*) - initialized (default) to 0 (this is the one you're actually seeing)

I replicated your code with minor changes - the most important one is the extra (regular *.dll* export) file

*Export.h*:

```c
#pragma once

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  if defined(DLL0_STATIC)
#    define DLL0_EXPORT_API
#  else
#    if defined(DLL0_EXPORTS)
#      define DLL0_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#    else
#      define DLL0_EXPORT_API __declspec(dllimport)
#    endif
#  endif
#else
#  define DLL0_EXPORT_API
#endif
```

Below are 2 screenshots took during debugging:

1. Constructor

   [image: img00]
2. Getter

   [image: img01]

Looking at the *number* member address (red boxed), it's different in the 2 pictures (note that the instance address (*this*) is the same), so there's the proof.

Now, looking at the bigger picture, this seems like an *XY Problem*. 
I don't see any scenario (except for curiosity purposes only) where this design would fit, because
the static member is set to the constructor argument, meaning that a new instance will overwrite whatever previous ones have set, so at a point in time, the member will contain the argument that was passed to the last instance constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The #include instruction really means include. It effectively inserts the content of the included header file into the source file(.c/.cpp) (recursively).

So, when you (directly or indirectly) include your template.h in multiple source files, every source file will allocate it's own static `number` filed. If these source files are compiled into one target file, there will be a link error. But if they are compiled into difference DLL/EXEs, they will keep their own copy of that static filed.

This is similar to global varibles, in which you generally have to use `extern` keyword to tell the compiler this is just a declaration, not a definition.